# Error:invalid_client OAuth2 YouTube data API

Tags: javascript, youtube, oauth-2.0

I am using YouTubeAPI in Javascript with OAuth2.

I created a new project in google developers console,
I enabled YouTube Data API v3, 
I set my OAuth Consent : [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soXiw.png)

I created a OAuth 2.0 client : [link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWcIP.png)

When I am using javascript to use this API (accordingly with youtube api-samples), I have this response :

401. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_client

Application: TESTAPPLICATION

You can email the developer of this application at: myemail@myemail.com

no registered origin

Is it comming from something i missed in my code or did i make a bad configuration in google developers console ?